# Formatting form data?

Tags: python, urllib

I need to convert the form data below to a slightly different format to be able to submit correctly.

I have this form data.

```
PaReq:eJxdUt1ugjAYvfcpyB6AlvpTMLUJG1vmEp2Z7mKXpHRIVMBSBvr0a9FatAlJz/lO6en5PrLZCs6j
NWe14HTgOGTBqypOuZMls6cydrGHgwn2UOA/6bISrMIvfrzsFfrjosqKnHoudBEBBpryggu2jXNp
CEXF7Pg8X9JRgAIICbhCWz9wMY+oj/EYDyfwugi40FaWxwdOPyJnXRZCVgR02JZZUedSnKiPJgQY
YMu12NOtlOUUgKZp3N+ikGUsRbF3WeHWO0CAVphXgMdnkFWtiap/Y5sldBGFjf1Yuzzv0PL8evrc
pDMCtMLqk1hyiqCHoT/0HIimCE/HmICO78V10OapNxy5QaDiukBbL7WT8CbSmj7VS6QWgufMRGKQ
FfC2LHKuzqg+3vY9v7xidBg5VTcryqfGt4QeAyEv73c9Z1J1LwxZ+takbbhOfr6h9sjC65rpSehE
d4Yy1TXkQb9zlNkWEmD+r642A6n71A0vHRBwP9j/7TDLBQ==
TermUrl:https://www.footpatrol.co.uk/checkout/3d
MD:
```

Wanted format:

```
PaReq=eJxdUt1ugjAYvfcpyB6AlvpTMLUJG1vmEp2Z7mKXpHRIVMBSBvr0a9FatAlJz%2FlO6en5PrLZCs6j%0D%0ANWe14HTgOGTBqypOuZMls6cydrGHgwn2UOA%2F6bISrMIvfrzsFfrjosqKnHoudBEBBpryggu2jXNp%0D%0ACEXF7Pg8X9JRgAIICbhCWz9wMY%2Boj%2FEYDyfwugi40FaWxwdOPyJnXRZCVgR02JZZUedSnKiPJgQY%0D%0AYMu12NOtlOUUgKZp3N%2BikGUsRbF3WeHWO0CAVphXgMdnkFWtiap%2FY5sldBGFjf1Yuzzv0PL8evrc%0D%0ApDMCtMLqk1hyiqCHoT%2F0HIimCE%2FHmICO78V10OapNxy5QaDiukBbL7WT8CbSmj7VS6QWgufMRGKQ%0D%0AFfC2LHKuzqg%2B3vY9v7xidBg5VTcryqfGt4QeAyEv73c9Z1J1LwxZ%2BtakbbhOfr6h9sjC65rpSehE%0D%0Ad4Yy1TXkQb9zlNkWEmD%2Br642A6n71A0vHRBwP9j%2F7TDLBQ%3D%3D%0D%0A&TermUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.footpatrol.co.uk%2Fcheckout%2F3d&MD=
```

I have tried this but seems to be a different format than what I need to submit correctly.
Code:

```
    import urllib.parse

print(urllib.parse.quote_plus('''PaReq:eJxdUt1ugjAYvfcpyB6AlvpTMLUJG1vmEp2Z7mKXpHRIVMBSBvr0a9FatAlJz/lO6en5PrLZCs6j
NWe14HTgOGTBqypOuZMls6cydrGHgwn2UOA/6bISrMIvfrzsFfrjosqKnHoudBEBBpryggu2jXNp
CEXF7Pg8X9JRgAIICbhCWz9wMY+oj/EYDyfwugi40FaWxwdOPyJnXRZCVgR02JZZUedSnKiPJgQY
YMu12NOtlOUUgKZp3N+ikGUsRbF3WeHWO0CAVphXgMdnkFWtiap/Y5sldBGFjf1Yuzzv0PL8evrc
pDMCtMLqk1hyiqCHoT/0HIimCE/HmICO78V10OapNxy5QaDiukBbL7WT8CbSmj7VS6QWgufMRGKQ
FfC2LHKuzqg+3vY9v7xidBg5VTcryqfGt4QeAyEv73c9Z1J1LwxZ+takbbhOfr6h9sjC65rpSehE
d4Yy1TXkQb9zlNkWEmD+r642A6n71A0vHRBwP9j/7TDLBQ==
TermUrl:https://www.footpatrol.co.uk/checkout/3d
MD:'''))
```

Is this obtainable with python? And what do i need to do to achieve the wanted end result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your paraneters are separated by newlines you can use the `splitlines` method to get a list of parameters, and use `re.split` on each item to get a list with name, value.
Then apply `quote_plus` on each name and value, `'='.join` them and `'&'.join` all parameters.

```
import urllib.parse
import re

data = '''PaReq: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
TermUrl:https://www.footpatrol.co.uk/checkout/3d
MD:'''

data = [re.split(':(?!//)', line) for line in data.splitlines()]
data = '&'.join('='.join(urllib.parse.quote_plus(i) for i in l) for l in data)
```

If your data is split by newlines arbitrarily, you could join the lines and split by name. Then `zip` names and values, quote and join.

```
data = ''.join(data.splitlines())
data = zip(['PaReq', 'TermUrl', 'MD'], re.split('PaReq:|TermUrl:|MD:', data)[1:])
data = '&'.join('='.join(urllib.parse.quote_plus(i) for i in l) for l in data)
```

If you want to keep the newline cheracter, use only the last two lines in the second code snippet.